# Put keyword in a library in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, keyword

I have a lot of automated test cases with Robot Framework and, consequently, I have more and more keywords. It's a bit difficult for me to bring order.

My question is if I can include my keywords in a library. If this is possible, how can I do it?

Thank you.
Marta

Comment: how that will help you ? can you provide an example and bit more description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create libraries - [Creating test libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries).

However, moving keywords into a library will not bring order to your system. You will only move the disorder to another place.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your test scripts maintainable deals for the most part in having a certain structure to your work. This applies to Robot Framework as much as it does to any other language.

In Robot Framework we use [Resource Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files) to store keywords that we want to reuse across multiple [Test Case files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-cases). Thought these links you should be able to learn more on how to do this. You can import Resource Files in a Resource file, so chaining them.

As for what to put in these files that is often a personal preference. However, typically adhering to development principles like [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and most importantly Common Sense works best.

I'd advise adhering to principles instead of to fixed structure. Separate Data from Process logic, abstract the UI from your Process logic and model your process logic as close to Business Processes as possible.

As for converting keywords to Python Code. If the logic in your resource files means you use a lot of keywords for a specific feature automation, then perhaps this makes sense. But keep in mind that for maintainability you will then be more heavily dependent on the Python skills in your organisation.